# Printing (paper!) CSS-Styled XML with a shell command

Tags: xml, unix

Since it is possible to style an arbritary XML with (print-oriented) CSS you can also print that out by using a Webbroser and hitting CMD+P.

My Question now is: Is there an easy possibility to print a CSS-Styled XML on the server side with a tool that is executable as a shell command?